# How to change the some sample names into symbols such as dots or stars in PCA in R?

Tags: r, symbols, pca, sample

There are 2 categories of 10 data (SNP1-SNP10), I hope to use to symbols to separate them, but how write codes in R. My codes are below:

```
data=read.table(file= "snp.txt",header= T,sep = "")
pca=prcomp(t(data),scale=TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
pca.data<-data.frame(Sample=rownames(pca$x), X=pca$x[,1], Y=pca$x[,2])
ggplot(data=pca.data, aes(x=X,y=Y,label=Sample))+geom_text()+theme_bw()+ggtitle("My PCR Graph")+xlab(paste("PC1 - ",pca.var.per[1],"%",sep=""))+ylab(paste("PC2 - ",pca.var.per[2], "%",sep=""))
```

Might make some changes from `Sample=rownames(pca$x)`?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use the `shape` aesthetic?

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/

For example:

`ggplot(data=pca.data, aes(x=X,y=Y,label=Sample, shape=Sample))+geom_point()+...`